# “Left identity” of Monad laws in Haskell is wrong

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory, haskell

[Monad laws in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws)

```
Left identity:  return a >>= f ≡ f a
Right identity: m >>= return ≡ m
Associativity: (m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

is widely known, and I think the "Left identity" rule does not make sense.

In category theory, it is true that Monads corresponds to Monoid, but this "Left identity" is twisting things around.

the binary operator `>>=` is a notation, so is `f a` or `f(x)` etc..

- `f(x)`
- `f a`
- `m >>= f`
- `monad.bind(f)`

In program semantics, all are the same, especially, when we define `f` always returns a monad value.

It's like "1" and "One" means the same entity in mathematics.

```
1 ≡ "One"  // Some Identity! 
// this rule must be satisfied in terms of category theory!??
```

So-called "Left identity" in Haskell Monad law: `return a >>= f ≡ f a` is nothing to do with category theory but simply notation.

On the other hand "Right identity": `m >>= return ≡ m` makes sense because according to the notation replacement, it can be rewritten to `return m ≡ m`, and surely this defines one of monad feature or a rule of identity.

(edit)

- `TTX = TX`
- `unit(unit(a)) = unit(a)`
- `return m ≡ m`

whatever, the semantics is the same.

In the later part of `[Monad laws in Haskell][1]`, it makes an excuse saying

> Not in this form, no. To see precisely why they're called "identity laws" and an "associative law", you have to change your notation slightly.

then, it introduces "Kleisli composition operator" : `>=>`.

What?? The different operator is introduced, then they concluds:

> This is a very important way to express the three monad laws, because they are precisely the laws that are required for monads to form a mathematical category.

The widely known "Haskell monad laws" are based on the `bind` binary operator: `>>=`, but in fact, the "left identity" rule is nothing to do with catrgory theory but merely programming notation replacement, then later, by replacing the bind operator to "Kleisli composition operator" : `>=>`, it claims the notation replacement is based on category theory.

I think this fools the readers and is the source of confusion of Monad concept to beginers or all of us.

Probably, I also need to mention that this Monad laws are firstly fomalized  in [Monads for functional programming by Philip Wadler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf)

EDIT:

Well, I do not deny `return a >>= f ≡ f a` is a binary operator definition. It's a replacement of notation, and here is the thing.

notation replacement is nothing to do with category theory or "Left identity"  `

Comment: A little less attitude would go a long way. For reference, the monad laws were not invented by Phil Wadler (and of course he never said they were). As far as I know they were first used in the form we know them today by Roger Godement in the 1950's.

Comment: I don't see any answerable question, here. If you have a question (and not just "Am I right?", pelase), please edit your post to include it. I'd also recommend trimming down the text somewhat. It _usually_ doesn't need two screenfuls of browser text to ask a clear question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: the question was first asked on StackOverflow, which resulted in a rather "heated discussion" https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182205/discussion-on-question-by-bayesian-study-left-identity-of-monad-laws-in-haskel

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks. What I meant is the monad laws in Haskell (Kleisli triple), and I believe it's formalized by Phil Wadler .

Comment: It was Eugenio Moggi who first discovered the relevance of monads in (functional) programming. Phil Wadler's work has been immensly influential and he contributed a great deal of original ideas, but it just wasn't him who discovered what you are talking about. He *popularized* monads for functional programming very successfully, but that's a different thing.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yeah, I know that, too. (I watched he mentioned that in his lecture on YouTube), and I still think he is the first guy who introduced 3 monad laws in Haskell (left&right and identity). Relating to this topic, I have post another question. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99036/monads-not-with-flatmap-but-flatunit I would appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be more precise. When you say that `f(x)`, `f a` and `m >>= f` are "the same", that does not make sense as written. `f(x)` and `f a` cannot be the same, they do not even use the same variables. Did you mean to compare `f(u)`, `f u` and `u >>= f`? It is true that `f(u)` and `f u` are the same thing, but `u >>= f` is not. If `f` has type `a -> m b` (where `m` is the monad) then

- in `f u` the type of `u` must be `a`, but
- in `u >>= f` the type of `u` must be `m a`

So the types don't even match. Furthermore, if you look at concrete examples, you will see that `>>=` is not "just notation". It actually does things.

If we now look at the left identity law

```
return u >>= f  ≣  f u
```

we see that we cannot just rewrite the left-hand side to `f u`, or even `f (return u)`. We must take into account what `return` and `>>=` do in a specific case. For instance, in the [list monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/List) we define

```
return x = [x]
```

and

```
(xs >>= f) = concat (map f xs)
```

The left identity law holds *because* of how `concat` and `map` work:

```
return x >>= f      ≣
[x] >>= f           ≣
concat (map f [x])  ≣
concat [f x]        ≣
f x
```

The above calculation was not just "notation"!